# What package or class defines an \email macro?

Tags: packages, errors

A colleague sent to me a manuscript written in Ubuntu. I am using Mac OS X Snow Leopard and I only have  trouble when I compile the document due to the latex command `\email`. It seems it is not recognised. What package should I install or what else should I do?

Comment: You need to provide the right details to get help (and to write a good question). Could you please provide [a minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5701) and the error you get when you compile the document.

Comment: Try putting `\show\email\def\email#1{\relax}` before the first occurrence of `\email` and see if you can now compile, and tell us what Latex tells you about the contents of \email.  This isn't a solution but a diagnostic, since it throws away information.

Comment: `moderncv` defines `\email` at least the newer versions of it do...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know that `\email` is defined in `lettre.cls` the french version of letter.cls but this macro is perhaps defined in another class or package

Answer (score 4):

Very Simple Solution

All you need is just define `\email` in your preamble as follows

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\newcommand*{\email}[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}} }
```

which defines your desired email format: monofont space, hyperlink to mail directly.
you can then use the command `\email`, for example:

```
\email{anyone@anywhere.com}
```

N.B. Sometimes `\email` command is reserved in the class you using for any reason, you can change it to anything else, e.g. `\emailf`, `\emaill`, ... etc.

Answer (score 3):

The AMS document classes (`amsart` and `amsbook`) define the `\email` command.

Answer (score 2):

Extrapolating from your last question, the `llncs` class has a `email` macro. In the preamble, use it like this:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
...
\author{First Author}
\institute{
  Example Institute,
  Example Road 12,
  \email{author@example.com}
}
\begin{document}...
```

Actually, all the macro does is to set the email address in a typewriter font.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Corentin ??? Read the title of this question, and my answer again. The `llncs` class provides an `\email` macro, I mean, it does!

Comment: Sorry for the unfriendly, automatic message from the review tools... What I meant to say was that your answer looked more like a comment in the present form. Perhaps supplementing it with a MWE would turn it into a valuable answer (but this also applies to the original question which is a bit vague in my humble opinion)